# Rails ActionMailer with SendGrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid to send emails on Heroku...

The problem so far is while it works great on Heroku, on my local host it fails.

Right now I have SendGrig install here, config/setup_mail.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port           => "25",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN']
}
```

What's a Heroku/SendGrid way to allow me to make sure my mailers work in DEV. Is this setup_mail.rb file a good thing? Should it be in the env file? Any other thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using config/environments/[development.rb | production.rb] as tfe mentioned above sounds like its the way to go. Just put the ActionMailer configuration in either of those files and change it to suit the development|production environment.

You can also find your SendGrid credentials used by Heroku by issuing the following command:

> heroku config --long

These credentials are used for all SendGrid authentication (SMTP Auth, Website login to view stats, etc., API access)

-- Joe

SendGrid

Comment: It seems that `heroku config --long` doesn't work anymore. `heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `heroku config:get SENDGRID_PASSWORD` get you the same information though.

Comment: or simply `heroku config` without the params

Answer (score 4):

Just set environment variables on your development environment for `SENDGRID_USERNAME`, `SENDGRID_PASSWORD`, and `SENDGRID_DOMAIN`. Then it will work.

You can get the correct values for these from your Heroku app. Open heroku console and get the values of `ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']` and so on.

Or just use a different set of SMTP settings locally. Or use sendmail or something.

Comment: Thanks, "use a different set of SMTP settings locally" that's exactly what I'm trying to learn how to do. What's the right way in Rails to do this setting across envs?

Comment: I believe you can just set the `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` in each of your environment initializer files (`config/environments/foo.rb`). I'm not exactly certain on the Rails Way here; I haven't configured mail in this way in a while.

Comment: I run several apps on Heroku with SendGrid, but I ran into the same issue (desiring to send mail locally as well as on Heroku). What I did was just go to SendGrid myself and sign up for an account. Then I had the username and password which I could set in the app for all environments, and those credentials weren't locked up inside the `ENV` of the Heroku app.